# How to add an array as an attribute value in Algolia Search index?

Tags: node.js, arrays, algolia

Im trying to add an array to an algolia index object. Im using parameters in a url request to do this. Ive confirmed the parameters come through as expected as an array of strings. this is in the context of a node.js server.

all the ways ive tried to update an existing algolia index object, it never works.

most recently i tried looping the items in the url parameter array and one-by-one submitting to algolia like:

```
router.get('/update', (req, res) => {
    console.log("[ /algolia/update ]")
    console.log("req.query: " + JSON.stringify(req.query))

    const update = {
        objectID: req.query.id
    }
    req.query.array.forEach((item, i) => {
        update.array = {
            _operation: 'AddUnique',
            value: item
        }
        index.partialUpdateObject(update)
            .then(({ objectID }) => {
                console.log("Algolia update " + (i + 1) + " of " + req.query.array.length + " success")
            })
    })
})
```

ive also just tried adding the whole array at once to the already-existing object. neither approaches have worked. anyone know how this is done? P.S. I'm using postman for testing at the moment

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be necessary, you can simply use:

```
index.partialUpdateObject({
   objectID: req.query.id,
   array: req.query.array
})
```

Comment: i used `AddUnique` because i will be adding an entire list of categories every time a users category is updated, and only want the newly added value, not all the previous values to be duplicated. but it still isnt registering in the algolia dashboard @redox

Comment: I have it working now, using your snippet. but does this create multiple deletes/writes? say if I have 3 indices in the array, then update it only keeping one index, does this snippet remove each index, and replace it with the one write? thereby creating 4 billable-events? @redox